# Using metamask to connect to another node on the same network

Tags: nodes, ethereum, rpc, metamask

I am trying to connect my metamask to my node which is running on `computer 2`. `computer 2`is a server that is running windows and runs geth with the flags -rpc and -rpcport *port number*. I have metamask with my main computer, `computer 2`. I want to use my node on the other computer, but when i do as a custom rpc http://192.168.86.21:*port number* metamask wont connect. running a light node on `computer 1` and using metamask to connect to localhost, works fine.

How should i connect from `computer 1` to `computer 2`?

*when i say port number, i specify my custom port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by using a reverse proxy with nginx

Answer (score 0):

In the computer 2, you should add `--rpcaddr "*"` when you run `geth`.
And make sure that your firewall accepts remote connections. You can test it by run command `telnet <computer2's ip> <port>` from the computer 1.

Comment: Why telnet? Couldnt i just use ssh? @van c

Comment: Yes, you can use whatever you want to test that you can access to computer 2 from computer 1. @TennisBowling

Comment: great! im not in town, so im going to see in a week or so.

Comment: It when i do --rpcaddr "*" it tells me this:


Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp: lookup *: no such host